# Processing rect() causes image to be draw instead of rectangle?

Tags: processing, artifacts

In my game there are enemies wandering around, their `draw()` method is simple:

`core.displayBuffer` is a `PGraphics` object that is draw onto the screen at the end of `draw()`.

```
        if(facingRight) {
            core.displayBuffer.image(image,
                    x, y + offsetY, 80, 80);
        } else {
            float tX = -core.camera.x+core.game.width/2f + x;
            float tY = -core.camera.y+core.game.height/2f+ y;

            core.displayBuffer.pushMatrix();

            core.displayBuffer.translate(core.camera.x-core.game.width/2f,
                    core.camera.y-core.game.height/2f);
            core.displayBuffer.translate(tX, tY);
            core.displayBuffer.scale(-1, 1);

            core.displayBuffer.image(image,
                    -80, offsetY, 80, 80);

            core.displayBuffer.popMatrix();
        }
```

Then when we are going to draw walls, we just draw a coloured rectangle like this:

```
    core.displayBuffer.noStroke();

    if(destroyed) {
        core.displayBuffer.fill(0, 0, 0, 16);
        core.displayBuffer.rect(x, y, w, h);
    } else {
        core.displayBuffer.fill(64);
        core.displayBuffer.rect(x, y - WALL_HEIGHT, w, h);
        core.displayBuffer.fill(32);
        core.displayBuffer.rect(x, y + h - WALL_HEIGHT, w, WALL_HEIGHT);
    }
```

But for some reason, the walls have the texture of the enemies? Here's the loop in which the objects are drawn:

```
    PMatrix displayMatrix = displayBuffer.getMatrix();
    PMatrix bloomMatrix = bloomLayer.getMatrix();
    PStyle displayStyle = displayBuffer.getStyle();
    PStyle bloomStyle = bloomLayer.getStyle();

    onScreenObjects.forEach(o -> {
        displayBuffer.setMatrix(displayMatrix);
        bloomLayer.setMatrix(bloomMatrix);
        displayBuffer.style(displayStyle);
        bloomLayer.style(bloomStyle);
        o.draw(this);
    });

    displayBuffer.setMatrix(displayMatrix);
    bloomLayer.setMatrix(bloomMatrix);
    displayBuffer.style(displayStyle);
    bloomLayer.style(bloomStyle);
```

Here's example of the results, red rectangles are around the walls, that are drawn incorrectly.
Also the bullets are flickering for some reason? These 2 bugs don't appear when I don't draw the enemies onto the screen (or I draw just rectangles instead), so that means, that the `image()` is doing something weird in the background?

[image: Result]

Project's source code is at https://github.com/Matrx007/TheLostBits

Ask for additional info if needed!

---

Nvidia Quadro 4000.
Graphics card driver is from 2016, can't upgrade it, all other games are working fine tho.
Processing version: 3.5.3 (Library)
Operating System and OS version: Windows 10 build 17134

Possible Causes / Solutions:
Maybe that the `image()` manipulates the current texture being used and `rect()` uses the texture?

---

### SOLVED

The solution was, that Processing can't draw onto more than one PGraphics at a time. I had beginDraw() called on two PGraphics and I was drawing to both of them at the same time, now I separated them, and the bug is gone! Better explanation here: https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5863

Comment: Please start by creating a [mcve] of your code: remove all the code that nothing to do with drawing these rectangles, because in doing so you're going to find exactly when those rectangles suddenly work normally again, in which case you found the problem and you're done, or you haven't and you now have demo code that's small enough to post in its entirety.

Comment: What do I remove and what do I keep?! I have no idea what part of it is working and what part is not.

Comment: See link. Focus on just the one thing that you see going wrong, and start removing code that you know has nothing to do with it: any code that draws things unrelated to rectangles: get rid of it. Any code that handlers user interaction: get rid of it. Any code that scrolls the screen, moves the camera, tracks scores: get rid of it. Start stripping away _everything_ that has nothing to do with drawing these rects, until either suddenly the rects draw fine (in which case, look at the last thing you removed for clues), or even in its most minimal form, rect() still misbehaves.

Comment: Creating a [mcve] is not about "I already know what the problem is", it's an exercise you do because _you don't know what the problem is_ so you start weeding: remove code, does the result change in terms of the problem you're seeing happen? No? That was not part of the problem. Repeat until it does. Then keep doing that for as long as necessary until you're basically left with "less than a pageful of code" and "_immediately_ seeing the problem simply by running that code".

Comment: I created a simpler version of it, haven't been able to reproduce the bug yet, I will be home in 4 hours, I will continue working on it.